# How to refresh a chunk's diff, during `git add -p`

Tags: git, git-diff, git-add, convenience-methods

When staging files with `git add` in *patch mode* (`-p`) I sometimes find a mistake that I would like to correct, before keeping on with *add*ing further changes.

Many possible options are prompted: *conf`y`rm*, *plu`n`k*, *`s`plit*, *`e`dit*, etc..

But I don't see any way to **re-read the file and refresh the diff** so I can see new updated changes, that I might have carried on in the meanwhile.

Usually I need to `q`uit *git-add*, and re-run it (eventually having to re-skip all eventual chunks, in order to finally get again to the chunk I edited during the previous `git add -p`).

***Is there any (native, or artificial) way for making the process more convenient and just refresh the diff?***

Comment: No, there is no way to make it more convenient. Well, you can get the source code and change it and build a new version of Git. So, yes: change Git. :-)

Comment: Mmmh, then writing a hacky shell script, able to track choices over the chunks via */dev/stdin* and replay them on `[CTRL] + R`, might possibly require less work ;)

Comment: Well, yes, anything that plays with the inputs like that... :-)